# read from a file at different offsets in linux

Tags: linux, filesystems, posix

Is it possible to read from a file at different offsets in one system call (with out seeks inbetween), like windows overlapped IO?

Comment: 1. Please reward the people who have helped you in the past and accept answers to your older questions. 2. Please explain in more detail what you want to accomplish. Why do you think you can't just seek, read, seek again, read again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question doesn't make sense. Windows overlapped I/O is simply an asynchronous method for reading (in this case) the file. It allows your thread to do something else while waiting for the I/O to complete.

You *cannot* use it to read multiple sections of a file without intervening seeks, in a single call.

You *can* use it to have concurrent accesses going on at the same time but you have to specify each time what segment of the file you want (in other words, implicit seeking) but you have to do this as multiple calls, one per segment.

If you want asynchronous I/O under Linux, DeveloperWorks has an interesting article on the `aio` stuff [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-async/), available from Kernel version 2.6 onwards.

Keep in mind that asynchronous I/O (even under Windows) is probably not going to benefit you that much for fast "devices" like a local hard disk. It's probably not worth the extra effort in coding for that use case. Where it comes into its own is with relatively slow devices like network storage or socket communication, where you may be able to get quite a bit of work done before the I/O completes.

Comment: My problem is that the multiple seeks and reads, even if to consecutive offsets, is adding too much  time, slowing IO.  So I think having things done in one call would be faster, but it seems like there is no way.

Comment: No, there is no way. And async I/O _will_ slow things down if the request is already fast (see my final paragraph). If you're doing sequential stuff, you're already getting the benefits of read-ahead caching. Another possibility is to `mmap` the file into memory and let Linux itself worry about the I/O and paging of it.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do it in a single system call, but you can do it without seeking* by using the `pread(2)` system call. This system call takes an offset from the start of the file of where to read the data from. This allows you to read from a file descriptor without altering the current offset. `lseek(2)` will change the current offset.

* I am differentiating between a disk seek and an OS seek. Reading consecutive blocks in a file may or may not result in a disk seek. An OS seek is changing the current offset of a file for the next read/write position.

Answer (score 1):

The `readv` and `writev` system calls are the "scatter read" and "gather write" calls and if I understand your question do what you want.  The man page is short but should be sufficient.

Edit: I misread the question, as pointed out in the comments.  What is being asked for looks more like `preadv`, which (along with its parallel `pwritev`) was introduced in Linux 2.6.30 and is described at http://lwn.net/Articles/164887/

Further edit: I previously thought that the iovec extensions made it into `preadv`/`pwritev`, but they didn't: see http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/readv.2.html

Comment: I think that's the _opposite_ problem you're solving there. It reads _one_ contiguous block from the file and scatters it to multiple buffers. I don't think it allows you to access non-contiguous parts of the file.

Comment: The `preadv` and `pwritev` system calls were added in Linux 2.6.30.

Comment: And they are still at one offset in the file — I had been mistakenly thinking that the iovec extensions had made it in for preadv/pwritev. Oh, well.